# Maintain relationship between variables when saving to / loading from JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Is there any way of saving a variable to a json file that gets saved as a variable and opened as a usable variable later:

```
import json

variable = 123
test = {
    1 : 1*variable,
    2 : 2*variable,
    3 : 3*variable
}

with open('json_data_Test.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(test,outfile)

variable = 200

with open('json_data_Test.json', 'r') as outfile:
    test2 = json.load (outfile)

print(test2)
```

Output:
`{'1': 123, '2': 246, '3': 369}`

Desired Output:
`{'1': 200, '2': 400, '3': 600}`

The aim is to when the json file is reopened and brought into a dictionary, the values are changeable based on the new value of  `variable`.

Comment: No, there's no built-in way to do this in JSON. `1*variable` performs the calculation and just stores the result. There's no way to save the expression in JSON.

Comment: You could save a string that you parse as a template after loading the JSON.

Comment: Instead of "usable variable", you might want "relationship between variables", or "reactive variable"? A variable is generally considered "usable" whether or not it gets automatically recalculated when something else changes. What you're asking to do here smells very much like reactive programming -- see https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY for one example of folks building this on top of Python.

Answer (score 0):

No, because the multiplication operation was calculated and the result of that operation was stored in your json, which has no idea what `variable` is.

In fact, integers aren't mutable, so even if you ignore the json part and stick to python, once you have set the value of `variable = 123` and used it in `another = variable`, modifying `variable` isn't going to change the value of `another`.

If you know for sure that the three keys in your json dict are integer multiples of a single variable, you could calculate the value of the greatest common divisor using `math.gcd()`. Then, divide each value by this and multiply by the new value of `variable`.

```
with open('json_data_Test.json', 'r') as outfile:
    test2 = json.load (outfile)

old_variable = math.gcd(test2['1'], test2['2'])

for key in test2:
    test2[key] *= (variable / old_variable)
```

Now, `test2` is `{'1': 200.0, '2': 400.0, '3': 600.0}`

---

If you cannot guarantee that the GCD of the values in your dict will be the old `variable`, you should probably change the output object to save the value of `variable` in your json:

```
variable = 123
out_obj = {
    "variable": variable,
    "test": {
       1 : 1*variable,
       2 : 2*variable,
       3 : 3*variable
    }
}

with open('json_data_Test.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(out_obj,outfile)

variable = 200

with open('json_data_Test.json', 'r') as outfile:
    in_obj = json.load(outfile)

old_variable = in_obj["variable"]
test2 = in_obj["test"]

for key in test2:
    test2[key] *= (variable / old_variable)
```

Comment: The idea of storing the variable separately and using it to alter the stored states seems to be the most applicable to my scenario, my only worry is speed, but it should be fine on a small scale. Thanks, I would vote but do not have the reputation

Answer (score 0):

If you need something generic, and you DO NOT TAKE ANY INPUT FROM AN UNTRUSTED USER, you can use python's `eval`, and save the values as strings which will later be reevaluated with the new value of `variable`.
I suggest something like this:

```py
import json

variable = 123
test = {
    1 : '1*<variable>',
    2 : '2*<variable>',
    3 : '3*<variable>',
    4 : ['<variable>+5', '<variable>+6'],
}

with open('json_data_Test.json', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json.dumps(test))

variable = 200


def evaluate(d):
    # recursively go through every value of the dictionary, and replace the <variable> wildcard with it's value, and then use `eval`.
    if type(d) == str:
        return eval(d.replace('<variable>', str(variable)))
    
    for k, v in d.items():
        if type(v) in [list, tuple]:
            d[k] = [evaluate(i) for i in v]
        else:
            d[k] = evaluate(v)
    return d


with open('json_data_Test.json', 'r') as outfile:
    data = outfile.read()
    evaluated = evaluate(json.loads(data))
    print(evaluated)
```

Again, if you accept any sort of untrusted user input, avoid using this at all costs, as it will allow that user to run arbitrary python code, which is a huge security vulnerability.